# Reduce size of tlog files produced by compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Since our build on the build server is more and more slowing down I tried to find out what could be the cause. It seems it is mostly hanging in the disk IO operations of the `.tlog` files since there is no CPU load and still the build hangs. Even with a project containing only 10 cpp files, it generates ~5500 rows in the `CL.read.1.tlog` file.
The suspicious thing is that the file contains the same headers over and over, especially boost headers which take up like 90% of the file.

Is this really the expected behavior that those files are so big and have redundant content or is maybe a problem triggered from our source code? Are there maybe cyclic includes or too many header includes that can cause this problem?

## Update 1

After all the comments I'll try to clarify some more details here.

1. We are only using boost by including the headers and linking the already compiled libs, we are not compiling boost itself
2. Yes, SSD is always a nice improvement, but the build server is hosted by our IT and we do not have SSDs available there. (see points below)
3. I checked some perfcounters especially via perfmon during the compilation. Whereas the CPU and Memory load are negligible most of the time, the disk IO counters and also queue sizes are quite high all the time. Disk Activity - Highest Active time is constantly on 100& and if I sort the Total (B/sec) it's all full with tlog files which read/write a lot of data to the disk.
4. Even if 5500 lines of tlog seem okay in some cases, I wonder why the exact same boost headers are contained over and over. [Here](https://gist.github.com/Danielku15/5d4ab17f00b73eea800b86e530f409bf) a logfile where I censored our own headers.
5. There is no Antivirus influencing. I stopped it for my investigations since we know that it influences our compilation even more.
6. On my local developer machine with SSD it takes ~16min to build our whole solution, whereas on our build server with a "slower" disk it takes ~2hrs. CPU and memory are comparable. The 5500 line file just was an example from a single project within a solution of 20-30 projects. We have a project where we have ~30MB tlog files with ~60.000 lines in it, only this project takes half of the compilation duration.
7. Of course there is some basic CPU load on the machine during compilation. But it is not comparable to other developer machines with SSDs.
8. Our .net solution with 45 projects is finished in 12min (including setup project with WiX)

As on developer machines with SSDs we have at least a reduction from 2hrs to 16mins with a comparable CPU/memory configuration my assumption for the bottle neck was always the hard disk. Checking for disk related operations lead me to the tlog files since they caused the highest disk activity according to permon.

Comment: The most obvious first step is to make sure you're writing them to an SSD.   Next, you likely have a configuration error somewhere if it's bogging you down this much, but I know little about VS.

Comment: You say it *seems* it is mostly hanging in .tlog disk I/O. Better make sure of that before trying to optimize the wrong thing. Since you use Boost, isn't it possible builds just take a long time because of the large Boost headers with a lot of dependencies, so a lot of header files which all have to be read from disk and processed? 5500 lines in a .tlog file is peanuts in comparision with all header files which have to be read, even when not using Boost but just the standard library.

Comment: Do you maybe have massive amounts of nodes in your build dependency tree?  It looks like this is created by the msbuild process which figures out which things need to be built and when.  Do you maybe procedurally generate thousands of header files which each include boost libraries or something like that?

Comment: @stijn he said there's no CPU load, so it's not compiling boost stuff.  The 5500 lines was on what is presumably a different, much smaller build of 10 files.   5500 lines wouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: "only 10 cpp file" and "boost headers" are highly incompatible statements. Every `#include`d file  counts.

Comment: @xaxxon no CPU load doesn't in any way mean it is 100% sure the disk I/O for .tlog files is the bottleneck, it's almost crazy to just assume that. There is way more other disk I/O going on during a build. Like reading all boost header files, as I already said.

Comment: @Frank the point being that it's 10 TUs

Comment: @stijn I didn't say it meant it was tlog, just that it wasn't compiling boost like you suggested.  I never assumed anything.  Reading the boost header files, however, is meaningless.   They are tiny and will immediately be cached so they won't be read repeatedly from disk.   However, writing lots of large object files back out to the disk can cause issues.  SSDs help with that, too.

Comment: @xaxxon Compiler I/O performance is based on number and sizes of files, not TUs. There being only 10 TUs is irrelevant if half of boost is included in one of them.

Comment: @xaxxon I didn't suggest the bottleneck is simply 'compiling' boost, I said "reading and processing". "Reading" meaning disk I/O. E.g. read first Boost header, couple of thousands of lines, process it (you likely won't see much CPU from just the preprocessing), scan for #includes, then find those and read from disk, again thousands of lines, etc.

Comment: @stijn the entirety of the boost header files is 128MB.  "won't see much CPU from just the preprocessing" -- what do you think DOES the preprocessing?   How slow do you think disks are and do you know that OS's cache commonly used files in memory?

Comment: @frank What do you mean by "compiler I/O performance"?

Comment: Well if you'd stop editing your comments to say different things every couple of minutes maybe we could have a sane conversation. Anyway: yes the CPU does preprocessing - what else - my claim is that it might be insignificant enough the OP didn't see it (since OP deosn't mention how exactly it was measured). Also, stop assuming that because in your particular experience reading Boost headers from disk isn't a bottleneck, that it cannot be the case on a different machine. Like, on a crappy disk with not much cache, or any other problem in the huge pipeline from disk to software.

Comment: @xaxxon It means the amount of time the compiler spends stuck in I/O operations, possibly due to contention, preemption, caching, network, or whatever else in the OS/hardware that is preventing the I/O from completing immediately. Also generaly linearly scaled by the number and size of files processed, which boost is notorious for exasperating.

Comment: @Frank are you suggesting the OS won't cache ~100MB of files and will instead read it off disk every single time?

Comment: @stijn The operating system will cache the files.   They are very small.  It will not repeatedly go to disk for them.  It has nothing to do with the cache physically on the disk.  I just wrote a test program that includes boost hana.   It took .55s to compile the first time with .35s of CPU.  Second run took .39s to compile with .35s of CPU.   repeatedly using header files is NOT a massive I/O load.

Comment: What exact time does it take to build 10 files? Are you using SSD? Is there any antivirus software installed?

Comment: @VTT very good call on the antivirus.  That murders writes.

Comment: I just added boost/xpressive to my test program -- 3.0s/2.2s (wallclock/cpu) for the first run, 2.3/2.1 for each subsequent run.   The OS is caching the header files.  It's not going to be some sort of unnoticeable amount of CPU while preprocessing regardless of disk speed because it's only going to be read off the disk once.

Comment: could it just be a bad disk in the machine?  have you run it on other computers?